# Tableau add formula to dashboard action filter?

Tags: tableau-api

I've got a workbook I'm building using public data https://public.tableau.com/profile/alee4645#!/vizhome/JSAClaimantsWardtimeseries/Dashboard1 
The basics are working as I want, you see the map, you click on one of the coloured areas and a time series chart appears below the map showing the change over time for that area.

I want to add a couple of comparisons to this data, for example I want the time series chart to show a line for the whole coloured area (Somerset) so people can see how one part of it compares to the overall average.
I have the figures as separate rows in the data but of course when the action filter is triggered they get filtered out along with everything else.

If I edit the action filter in the filter shelf for sheet 2, it has the condition tab and I was hoping I could add [ward code] = "E10000027" (the comparison data I want to use) to the formula box so it would also keep the relevant rows of data, but that stops the chart working altogether.

I could achieve it by getting people to choose an area from a parameter drop down but I'd rather let them click on the map so they don't need to know the name of the area they are interested in.

Can this be done?

Comment: You should be able to define a level of detail calculation to return the somerset average whatever the filter is set to. Look them up (I'll see whether I get time to explain in detail later, you might be able to work it out first).

Comment: Thanks, not got my head around LOD yet, I'll have a look!

Comment: Struggling to get my head around LOD calculations but I don't think it's going to help in this case.  I haven't got raw data to aggregate the Somerset figures, they are already calculated in the data I've downloaded.